# Is there any other solution for ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find analytical solution for the following ODE:

$\phi^{2}\phi^{\prime\prime\prime}+3\,\phi\phi^{\prime}\phi^{\prime\prime}-4\,\phi^{2}\phi^{\prime}=0,\;\phi=\phi(x)$

One possibility that I have tried is putting $\phi={\rm e}^{ax}$, which resulted in exact solution such as $\phi=\,{\rm e}^{\pm x}$.

Is there any other possible solution for this ODE?

Comment: [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2y%27%27%27%2B3yy%27y%27%27-4y%5E2y%27+%3D+0) gives various other solutions.

Comment: Certainly $\phi = C$ is a solution, since every term has a derivative in it.

Comment: @Mark You peoples always surprise me, thank a lot!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation can be written as $$\phi\bigg((\phi\phi')''-4\phi\phi'\bigg)=0.$$
So we let $u=\phi\phi'$ to get $u''-4u=0$. Solving this we get $$u=c_1e^{2x}+c_2e^{-2x}=\phi\phi'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dx}\phi^2\Longrightarrow \phi^2=c_1e^{2x}-c_2e^{-2x}+c_3.$$